# How to use rewrite function in ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC site?

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

I am deploying an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC website to an IIS server on Windows Server OS.

Suppose the site has the following base URL:

```
https://www.example.com/mysite/
```

When I make some updates to my website, I want to keep the old website as well. Because if something goes wrong with the updated site, I can immediately revert to the old website.

Therefore, instead of deploying the website to the URL above, I decided to deploy it to a URL with a version number as shown below.

1. `https://www.example.com/mysite/1.0/`
2. `https://www.example.com/mysite/2.0/`
3. `https://www.example.com/mysite/3.0/`

What I want to do is as follows:

When a user accesses the base URL, I want to display the contents of the latest version (3).

I want the base URL to remain displayed in the URL field of the user's browser.

I think this type of operation can generally be achieved using the rewrite function.

Furthermore, if the user accesses the URL with a version number, I would like to be redirected to the base URL.

I tried customizing `app.MapControllerRoute` in `Program.cs`, but it didn't work as I expected.

My question is as follows: what method can I use to do what I want?

Or, if you want to keep not only the latest version of your website but also past versions of your website, please let me know if there is a better way to manage it.

Comment: Rather, make use of tests to mitigate issues (as best possible) and use source control? If something goes wrong revert to the previous release?

Comment: If this is a static only content website (which I doubt) I see no problem. If it isn't then complexity rises. Are you using any database storage? With possible changes in schema, between releases? How would you solve conflicts where two or more versions of the application would access and modify the same resource, possibly in a slightly different way? Do you see how quickly maintainability of such solution becomes troublesome? Instead, I'd suggest researching deployment slots as a way to swiftly switch between deployed application versions.

Comment: Modern approaches are usually container based.

Comment: Would this help: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-URL-Path#aspnet-core

Answer (score 0):

> When I make some updates to my website, I want to keep the old website
> as well. Because if something goes wrong with the updated site, I can
> immediately revert to the old website.

Well based on your scenario and description, you could use a version control system to track changes in your codebase. Depending on your changes, it would allows you to easily revert to past versions if needed and even compare revisions to identify issues. In addition, you might have two or more site based on your requirement.

For instance, you may have production environment, Dev or UAT so that you do what you are trying to achieve using three different web application.

However, if want to use of URL rewriting middleware within IIS, you can do that, In that scenario, you could try as following:

```
services.AddRouting();
services.AddRewrite(options =>
{
    options.AddRewrite("^mysite/(?!3.0/)(.*)", "mysite/3.0/$1", false);
    options.AddRedirect("^mysite/(.*)/[0-9]+.[0-9]+/", "mysite/$1/"); 
});
```

**Note:** First URL rules would redirect to the latest version while the other would redirected from the versioned URL. [Please refer to this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#url-redirect), if you need [custom defination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#url-redirect).

Middleware DI:

In your program.cs register following middleware reference.

```
app.UseRewriter();
```

Routing Defination:

Within routing defination, use the route without version name. Do like below:

```
app.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

> What method can I use to do what I want?
>
> Or, if you want to keep not only the latest version of your website
> but also past versions of your website, please let me know if there is
> a better way to manage it.

Well, its arbitrary or completely depends on your requirement or personal reference. For example, if you think of convenience then version control could be the easy option but you need to manage them well or you need additional branch.

But using IIS rewrite module you can do that as well in that case, you must need to learn it accordingly. Other than something might not work or can broken. Thus, it can be quicker or even simpler way to deal with.

**Note:** If you would like to know more [details on IIS rewrite middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware), please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
I have made changes to the source code as per your instructions and tested them, but so far I am not getting the expected results.
I'll keep trying.
If I am successful, I will report here.

Comment: Are you getting any error or anything? , what results you are getting? Feel free to let me know.

Comment: My reply includes the source code.
If I reply here, the line breaks will be lost and the source code will be difficult to read, so I posted it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried is below.
First, I deployed the Ver3.0 site.

https://www.example.com/mysite/3.0/

Next, I deployed a simple site made using only the ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC template to the base site.
View is only Index and Privacy.

https://www.example.com/mysite/

At this time, the following error occurred.

HTTP Error 500.35 - ASP.NET Core does not support multiple apps in the same app pool
Common solutions to this issue:
Select a different app pool to host this app.

So I moved the Base site to the newly created application pool. As a result, the above error was resolved.

I don't know much about regular expressions, so when I did the rewrite experiment, I tried using a simple string like the one below.
I added these codes to the end of Program.cs on the Base site.

var options = new RewriteOptions()

.AddRewrite(regex: "^(Home/Index)", replacement: "3.0/Home/Index",false);

app.UseRewriter(options);

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

As a result, the following error was displayed.

https://www.example.com/mysite/Home/Index not found

HTTP ERROR 404

On the other hand, when I replaced the AddRewrite part above with the redirect operation as shown below, the redirection was successful.

.AddRedirect(regex: "^(Home/Index)", replacement: "3.0/Home/Index");

Therefore, I don't think there is anything wrong with giving arguments to regex or replacement.
That's all I know for now.
If I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.